# Planning to use https for an MVC website ( using domain/subdomains) - Best practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, subdomain, orchardcms

I have to build a new MVC 4 web site, In my default page I have a link to log users. I know that MVC have the ability to change the displayed windows inside the displayed page.

For security, I have to consider https for:

- Login view for customers.
- Login view for contacts to send their mail to the internal mail server.
- Login view to open mail in the internal mail server.

I wonder what should be the best practice regarding domain name splitting (layout), do I need to use only the main domain name and secure with only 1 SSL certificate, or may be have to use multiple subdomains like *.mydomain.com and use 1 certificate per subdomain.

To explain more:

what should be the behavior of SSL when the URL changes using the same domain name.

For example the following methods can be used to reach the same purpose:

https://www.domain.com/userlogin.aspx and https://www.domain.com/contact.aspx may be should use the same Certificate but if we use par exemple:

https://www.admin.domain.com/ and  https://www.mail.domain.com/ necessarily have to use two different certificates.

Comment: Or a wildcard certificate for `*.mydomain.com`...

Comment: Yes but a wildcard costs much, when we have to use 3 or 4 subdomains max, it is cheaper to buy 3 or 4 basic certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Areas? Is it a requirement to have, and I quote: **3 or 4 subdomains**? If not, then you could use areas, which might lead you to have something like this:

```
site.com/area/controller/action

site.com/customer/account/login
site.com/admin/users
```

Anyway **my** suggestion would be to take a look into Areas in MVC.

- [ASP.NET MVC 2 - Areas](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/aspnet-mvc-2-areas).
- [Using Areas in ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm).
- [Asp.Net MVC 2 Areas](http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-areas/).
- [ASP.NET MVC Areas - A Better Way To Structure The Application](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/asp-net-mvc-areasa-better-way-to-structure-the-application/).

These links should provide you a quick insight of what you could do with areas. And, again, **if it's not a requirement** to have several subdomains, you could do it with one certificate instead.